# Selenium Error in Python (macOS): Cannot connect to chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a simple script for selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

And always ends up with an error:

`raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}") selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Both my Chrome and chromedriver are on the latest version (121.0.6167.85), and chromedriver is already in `/usr/local/bin/`. I've tried adjusting `service` and `options`, as well as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service=webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

Neither of them worked.

Comment: You can try using [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) instead, it doesn't require a webdriver and is a much newer library.